# Unable to install Rtree 0.8.2 package on RHEL6 64-bit

Tags: python, redhat, rhel6

**UPDATE:**

If it also helps. I have root access.
Seems like I am not the only with the problem, but a couple had this problems
https://github.com/ioos/conda-recipes/pull/198
I had updated my core.py accordingly as documented in the link however I get a new error.

```
python setup.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    import rtree
  File "/home/ricson/Rtree-0.8.2/rtree/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .index import Rtree
  File "/home/ricson/Rtree-0.8.2/rtree/index.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/ricson/Rtree-0.8.2/rtree/core.py", line 113, in <module>
    rt = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'lib', lib_name))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /usr/lib/libspatialindex_c.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I do know that this is a directory issue but I did not install anything our of the ordinary. I installed libspatialindex 1.8.5 using .configure; make; make install; ldconfig; no more not less.

I am able to build and execute if I change

```
rt = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'lib', lib_name))
```

to

```
rt = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'local/lib', lib_name))
```

However, Rtree will fail 3 out of the 6 tests.

**ORIGINAL:**

I am trying to install Rtree module on python 2.6.6
however setup.py insists that I have libspatialindex 1.6 when I have clearly just installed libspatialindex 1.8.5

Did I miss some steps? The script below as prescribe by libspatialindex owner does return 1.8.5
(https://github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex/wiki/1.-Getting-Started)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <spatialindex/capi/sidx_api.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace SpatialIndex;

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        char* pszVersion = SIDX_Version();
        fprintf(stdout, "libspatialindex version: %s\n", pszVersion);
        fflush(stdout);
        free(pszVersion);
    }
```

However when I edited index.py in Rtree and I get version 1.6.1 when I have clearly installed 1.8.5

```
python ../setup.py
core.rt.SIDX_Version() 1.6.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    import rtree
  File "/home/ricson/Rtree-0.8.2/rtree/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .index import Rtree
  File "/home/ricson/Rtree-0.8.2/rtree/index.py", line 39, in <module>
    raise Exception("This version of Rtree requires libspatialindex 1.7.0 or greater")
Exception: This version of Rtree requires libspatialindex 1.7.0 or greater
```

Let me know if this needs to be moved to serverfault. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should probably be moved to ServerFault. But you will need to install libspatialindex which information on doing so can be found [here](http://libspatialindex.github.io/install.html). It may also be in the package manager. Try `sudo yum search spatial` to see if it exists within the Yum repos.

Comment: Thanks! will move this to serverfault. It is not in my repository. I had to download it from git and install on my own.

Comment: Did you make sure to run `sudo ldconfig` after installing libspatialindex? Also what is the output of `ldconfig -p | grep spatial`?

Comment: 2 new findings.
I did find someone else having the same problem. I tried applying the ammendments but I now get a new error. [https://github.com/ioos/conda-recipes/pull/198](https://github.com/ioos/conda-recipes/pull/198)

Another finding is that without ammending core.py, It will take the default spatialindex library that is installed on RHEL. I went to check and there is indeed spatialindex 1.6.1 install on RHEL by default.

Comment: What is the new error? You could edit your question with the new error.

Comment: Use RHEL 7 if you can, which already includes spatialindex 1.8.5 in EPEL. Other than that...it appears you have two versions of spatialindex installed. You'll need to locate and remove the other one, to start with.

Comment: Thanks michael but this is an enterprise machine. I have to make do with RHEL6. Am I allowed to delete a default installation?

Answer (score 0):

Will set this to closed for now. Settled with installing r-tree 0.6 which only needs spatialindex 1.5.0+

rtree will test 5/6 passed. My basic script work for now but will eventually need to remember that this may cause problems in the long run.